# Convenient posterior distribution for homogeneous bivariate Gaussian model

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, prior, conjugate-prior, uninformative-prior

For the model given by some independent pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ identically generated from a bivariate Gaussian distribution, there is the convenient semi-conjugate family of "Normal-Wishart" prior distributions. It is mainly convenient because the posterior distributions are easy to simulate, without resorting to MCMC techniques. In particular the Jeffreys non-informative prior is at the boundary of the semi-cojugate family and the Jeffreys posterior is easily simulated.

But for the case when we assume equal variance for $x_i$ and $y_i$, is there a posterior distribution which is easy to simulate and achieving a good "frequentist performance" such as the Jeffreys posterior ? (that is, roughly speaking, the frequentist coverage of the $95\%$ credibility intervals approximately is $95\%$, for usual parameters of interest).

Comment: Did you mean to say that we assume the variance of $x_i$ and $y_i$ are known?  Otherwise, if we assume equal but unknown variances for $x_i$ and $y_i$ then we can still use the Normal-Wishart prior.

Comment: @BabakP The common variance is unknown. How do you put a Wishart prior on a variance matrix with equal diagonal entries ?

Comment: If you're after frequentist intervals, go straight to modified profile likelihood, I say. It's almost the same thing as using a probability-matching prior, but with no detour through Bayes' theorem. (There's a close relationship between modified profile likelihood and so-called [integrated likelihood](http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=integrated+likelihood+severini).)

Comment: @Cyan I want a good frequentist performance but my parameter of interest is $\theta=f(\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma)$ for a complicated function $f$.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Is there a one-to-one transformation between, say,  $(\mu_1,\mu_2,\theta)$ and $(\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma)$? If so, then I still say modified profile likelihood. It'll take brain power, be computationally intensive, and you'll want to check coverage by simulation, but it *will* work.

Comment: @Cyan I think there is such a transformation but it is too complicated (it involves the Gauss cumulative function $\Phi$ several times). You propose the profile likelihood because you think there's no convenient prior ?

Comment: @Cyan Ooopss no sorry, the one-to-one transformation is very easy. Actually $\theta=\frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\sigma}$. What is the **modified** profile likelihood ? I would prefer a posterior distribution but I'm interested in your proposal too.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I propose profile likelihood approaches because they target frequentist coverage directly (and I presume you either have no relevant prior information or you want to exclude any such information from the analysis). Modified profile likelihood applies a third-order correction to the signed profile-log-likelihood-ratio test statistic, making its sampling distribution closer to normal. Google has [lots of good stuff](http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&q=modified+profile+likelihood). (I hope your correlation coefficient is positive...)

Comment: @Cyan Thank you, I'll look at this. Yes I aim to get a correct frequentist coverage, but I think a "convenient" noninformative prior would be less computationally intensive than profile likelihoods methods. Does the modified profile approach require optimization ?

Comment: @Cyan I have found a method here http://www.wvbauer.com/downloads/ci_for_d_summary.pdf (I have not studied it yet)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I'm pretty sure it does require optimization. My experience is limited to reading the documentation for and papers describing the [hoa](http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&q=brazzale+higher+order+asymptotics) S-PLUS library; the optimization code is built-in.